# DevTools is not showing JS sources

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

Chrome Version       : 115.0.5790.XX
OS Version           : OS Ventura 13.4.1

Since Chrome version 115.0.5790 I noticed that source files from my website are not showing anymore in the sources tab.

In any of previous versions this works fine (I tested install a previous version and it worked).

I also noticed that when I'm opening my website, that I want to debug, this message is logged on console:

"DevTools debugger is disabled because it is attached to a process that hosts multiple top-level frames, where DevTools debugger doesn't work properly. Please relaunch the browser with --disable-features=ProcessPerSiteUpToMainFrameThreshold to enable debugger."

I do not know if it is somehow related, I tried to search for that flag but it does not exist in chrome://flags

I also tried mix around with chrome://flags/#allow-insecure-localhost and sometimes it started working!! But other times don't, so I'm not sure what is really affecting this, so I'm a bit lost with solutions..

Other informations that may be usefull:

- this website is built using webpack, but sourcemaps always worked well until now
- images and css sources are shown, only javascript files are missing
- I have some collegues with the same OS and Chrome versions and this is not happening to them

Comment: Go to `chrome://flags/#enable-process-per-site-up-to-main-frame-threshold` and disable it. Also consider reporting the problem in https://crbug.com.

Comment: Like I wrote, that flag does not exist.
And already reported to them.

Comment: Your post doesn't specifically mention this exact flag. I guess it was added in Chrome 116 or 117, so try doing what the message says i.e. restarting with a command line.

Comment: Launching from terminal with that flag works, indeed.
But since last Chrome version on Mac is 115 and if that flag is posterior to that, maybe there is something wrong about that..